# How to invite users to test add-on before publishing?

Tags: google-workspace-add-ons

I'm currently developing a gmail add-on and am hoping to allow a few users internal to my team to test out the add-on prior to a public release. I was following the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/testing-gsuite-addons) from google that states

> You can allow other users to test the add-on by sharing the Apps Script project with their account (read access is required) and then prompting the users to follow the above steps.

I assume that 'read' access is equivalent to 'view' access, and have given a user 'view' access to the project.

The problem I'm running into is that even with 'view' permissions, users aren't able to do a test deployment and install the add-on to their gmail account. The blue 'Deploy' button simply isn't visible. Any ideas on how to get my add-on into a few users hands before publishing, but without giving them edit privileges?

Comment: Can't they make a copy of the script? This copy they would own and could deploy.

Comment: Yeah that could be a workaround, just a bit of a hassle to have them re-create another copy if anything does end up getting changed.

Comment: If you use Google Workspace then you can [publish the Add-On privately](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview#determine_your_audience) and you would have control over what version of the Add-On your test users are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

- One way to do it is to have the users copy your script and deploy it.
- Another is to [publish the Add-On privately](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview#determine_your_audience) and you would have control over what version of the Add-On your test users are seeing. *For this your users should be of the same Google Workspace domain*